# How to query for valid date which is in VARCHAR field using JPQL or Spring data jpa?

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I have to get the min date from varchar field type.
I am able to do it using native query like below:

```
select * from license where TO_DAYS(STR_TO_DATE(license_date, '%Y-%m-%d')) IS NOT NULL ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(verified_license_issued, '%Y-%m-%d') ASC LIMIT 1;
```

But I need to do it using JPA.
How to do it ?

Comment: why would you store a Date in a VARCHAR field?!

Comment: @BillyFrost that is client's table. we can't change to Date type.

Comment: so if you want to invoke SQL functions using JPQL you use JPQL `FUNCTION` as any JPA docs would tell you. Or you use a native query